# iptables-persistent / netfilter-persistent has (dependancy?) problem on 15.1

Tags: apt, iptables

I'm trying to install 15.1 x64 on a new VPS. The first thing I do is ssh in and define a few iptables rules to drop non-ssh traffic, and now want to make those rules persistent. So:

```
root@server:~# apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

This fails. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818931/debian-8-iptables-persistent) seems to indicate that the package got renamed and `update-rc.d` stopped accepting stop/start commands. As a result, apt-get can't install it. Does anyone know what the official (unofficial?) way of resolving this is? How do you set persistent iptables rules in 15.1?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this seems to be a manifestation of [Debian bug 124518](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=124518), which can be fixed by determining which module is causing the problem at startup (`journalctl -xn`), then removing it from `/etc/modules` as per [this post](http://maxvt.net/2015/09/13/linode-iptables-persistent.html).

After doing those steps, I was able to reboot, install iptables-persistent, and write persistent rules to /etc/iptables that were then loaded after a second reboot.